# How to move a table to the end of Word document?

Tags: ms-word, positioning

My problem is this...

I have a table in MS Word and I want this table to be at the bottom of the last page of the document. How can I achieve this?

That means if I have just half a page of text it would be at the bottom of page 1 but if I would have 1.5 page of text it would go to the end of page 2, I think you get the point now.

To make it even  more hard I already have another table that is at the end of the first page and that works ( made it using positioning settings).

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Place your cursor in a cell in the table and you see the table anchor appear at the upper left corner of the table.  Right mouse click and hold on the anchor and choose "Table Properties...".  In the "Text Wrapping" section of the "Table" tab, choose "Around".  Click "OK".
You can now position the table anywhere in your document by grabbing the table anchor.